# Instance variables assign value by reference in ruby

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I have a doubt that in ruby whether all the objects in ruby pass or assign value by reference. Because when I tried to assign a instance variable to local. Changes made to local affects in instance variable too.

Here is my code.

```
@name = {:a=> 'sfgs', :b=> 'sdfsd'}
name = @name
name.except!(:a)
```

when I print @name the :a key-value pair has been deleted. If so, any other way to prevent this. i.e Copying instance variable without reference.

Comment: Ruby is pass-by-value/copy. But in case of complex objects, the original value and its copy are references to an object somewhere else.

Comment: The rule of thumb is **never ever** use mutating methods.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: sometimes you have to, for performance reasons. But yes, this is a good default rule

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not with you, why? In general.

Comment: BTW, is `Hash#except!` valid [tag:ruby]? What version?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: here you go: https://pastebin.com/c84na4FS

Comment: (it gets worse with bigger strings)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201318/discussion-between-aleksei-matiushkin-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `deep copy`. Try this:

```
name = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(@name))

name.except!(:a)
p name
#=> { :b => "sdfsd" }
p @name
#=> { :a => "sfgs", :b => "sdfsd" }
```

Comment: Or simply don't use mutating `except!`

Comment: Here `@name.dup` would be enough.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: until someone decides to mangle the values :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev “here” is a keyword. I apparently know how `dup` works :-P